# MYSQL - INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table USER like this:

USER -> PRIMARY KEY (email,name)

```
email          name       points
abc@xcv.com    abc         12
fre@xcv.com    fre         18
```

Suppose now the user - abc won 10 more points.

insert the useremail name points if useremail,name doesn't exists in USER table.
If duplicate key found then only update the points column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax goes like this:

```
insert into users(email, name, points)
values('abc@def.com', 'abc', 10)
on duplicate key update points = points + values(points)
```